# how to detect a microsoft sculpt keyboard dongle?

Tags: usb, keyboard

I recently purchased a used microsoft sculpt keyboard (with mouse) in order to use it with Linux Mint 17.3

I was hopping that it would work out of the box, instead nothing works (yes, batteries are cheched). I tried to detect the dongle with

```
lsusb
```

but no microsoft device appeared. Should that appear with *lsusb* command, or there is another way to detect the dongle (provided that the dongle works)?

Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: if it is `usb` device, then yes, it must be showed by `lsusb` provided it got detected. The dongle itself usually requires no external power supply (batteries) and is powered by usb port. So, you must see  the dongle on usb bus even when you power off the keyboard and/or mouse

Comment: you can also try the command dmesg

Comment: what exactly should I look for, in the *dmesg* report? It shows some *"USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)]"*, even if the dongle is disconnected.

Comment: `dmesg` is a circular buffer, so it shows a bunch of most recent kernel messages. This is why you see the message about your dongle when it is disconnected. Now run `dmesg -w` (I hope you have quite recent kernel and dmesg) and try to plug/unplug your dongle. Then share the relevant results please

Comment: I ran `dmesg`, reboot and reran `dmesg`. I compaired the two reports but nothing relevant to the Microsoft dongle occurred, so I am afraid that this dongle is dead.